# How does Kanai's cube manage legendaries extracted affixes' roll?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I extract the legendary power from a legendary which orange affix roll within a certain range (e.g. [The Dead Man's Legacy 50-60](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dead-mans-legacy)) but the roll is too low (let's say 51%). If I later loot a 60% version of the legendary, can I extract it again to upgrade the cubed version ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need to worry about this, the extracted affix is always at its maximum possible roll. With the Dead Man's Legacy, if you extract a 51% one, the passive you can slot will be 60% anyway.